# Не показывается картинка из базы данных в Django проекте

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Столкнулся с проблемой, на сайте не показывается картинка из базы данных.

Картинка в модели бд:

```
image_news = models.ImageField()
```

Картинка на сайте показывается в виде иконки:

[image: Скриншот 1]

Но правильно определяется наименование картинки из бд (посмотрел через код элемента):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод картинки в шаблоне:

```
{% for post in object_list %}
    <a href="{{post.id}}">
      <h5>{{post.title}}</h5>              
     </a>
     <h6>{{post.date|date:"d-m-Y"}}</h6>
     <img src="{{post.image_news}}">
 {% endfor %}
```

Из-за чего такое может быть? Буду очень благодарен если отправите статью или документацию, где описан этот вопрос

Comment: Как вы выводите картинку на сайт? Приведите, пожалуйста, код представления или (и) шаблона, в котором это происходит

Comment: Можете ли Вы перейти по наименованию картинки и открыть его? (последний скриншот, 111111.jpg) И да, хотелось бы видеть код

Comment: @4500zenja По картинке перейти не могу

Comment: Обратите внимание, что сейчас путь **относительный** — чтобы получить картинку браузер добавит её название к текущему URL

Comment: @nomnoms12 дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выводите картинку, используя атрибут [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url):

```html
<img src="{{ post.image_news.url }}">
```

Подробнее: [Managing files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/).